# VBA Optionbuttons

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

My problem is that i have to copy some Optionbuttons from an Excel document to Access.

But there is coming an `Error 438?
The Erros is Coming`oWS.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Controls("OptionButton" & i).Value` on this part of the code.

When i write the code like this it works.

```
".Fields("id") = oWS.Worksheets("Tabelle1").OptionButton4.Value"
```

But i Have a lot of Optioinbuttons because of that i want to make a "for loop".

I have Access 2013.

This is the code:

```
Set oWS = oXL.Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("test")
         With rs
         'i = 14
            For i = 3 To 10
            .AddNew
               .Fields("id") = oWS.Worksheets("Tabelle1").Controls("OptionButton" & i).Value
             .Update
           Next i
         .Close
         End With
```

Comment: thx  i have edit some details i hope it is better now

Answer (score 1):

Sheets don't have a Controls-Collection, but an OLEObjects-Collection where you can find the OptionButtons. Try:

```vb
 .Fields("id") = oWS.Worksheets("Tabelle1").OLEObjects("OptionButton" & i).Object.Value
```